# Clone @Html.DropdownList using javascript Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

Hello I have the following problem: I have a table with some columns, which one of them is a @Html.Dropdownlist that has already been populated. I'm trying to clone that by clicking a button using javascript. I'm able to clone all the row but after I clone the @Html.Dropdownlist selection stops working. I'm able to open the @Html.Dropdownlist but I can't select the options. Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
@{
 DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();
 var actions_list = new SelectList(db.Actions.Select(f => new { f.Id, f.Action }), "Id", "Action");
    }


        <table>
         <thead>
 <tbody id="lines-event">
          <tr>
           <th>#</th>
           <th>Action</th>
           <th>Data</th>
           <th><button type="button" class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right" id="add_row"></button></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tr id='line-new-event'>
         <td class="col-md-1"></td>
         <td class="action col-md-3">@Html.DropDownList("Actions", actions_list, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", data_width = "100%"})</td>
         <td class="data"><input type="text" class="form-control edit_data" /></td>
         <td class="col-sm-1"><button type='button' class='btn glyphicon glyphicon-trash pull-right delete_row'></button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>


<script>
 $("#add_row").click(function () {
           function createGuid() {
                function s4() {
                    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1);
                }
                return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
            }

            var guid = createGuid();
            console.log(guid);
            var newLine = $('#line-new-event').clone().removeAttr('id');
            $(newLine).find('select').attr("id", guid);
            $(newLine).find('select').attr("name", guid);
            $(newLine).insertBefore($('#line-new-event'))
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi your code looks good are you sure is not just javascript error, try to see all your functions or scritps. I will give you a advice delete everything and leave just the function of clone if its work start to add the rest and see when it stop to works. I think will be some script that or class that is giving error.
You welcome